# Calling Stored Procedure having Table/TableType as In/OUT params from Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I am following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures) guide for calling my stored procedure. I searched around for other resources for an example where IN and OUT parameters are of type table but couldn't find one.

I am having error: `Cannot convert SQL type TABLE to Java type java.lang.Object`

Comment: Can you post what have you tried and what is not working instead of specifying the tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to know what exactly caused the problem. But I'm giving an example of a stored function that actually worked for me. Stored functions could be an alternative approach to stored procedures which need to return DTOs.

```
@Repository
public interface CustomRepository extends CrudRepository<YourObject, UUID> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * from your_stored_procedure(:key)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<YourObject> findAlldata(@Param("key") String key);

}


@Service
public class CustomService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomRepository customRepository;
    
    public List<YourObject> getAllData(String key) {
        List<YourObject> yourObjects = this.customRepository.findAlldata(key);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the stored function in Postgres. The `return` objects should have a similar structure for both the `repository` and the `procedure`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.your_stored_procedure(key text) RETURNS TABLE(id uuid, name character varying)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT
    id,
    name
    FROM public.your_table;
END;
$$;
```